# Are 'volatile' and 'side effect' related?

Tags: c++, volatile, side-effects

Just a beginner question.

In the code from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now), there is a comment saying, *"make sure it's a side effect"* on the line using `std::accumulate`.

1. What is the author's intention in saying this? Is it related to the `volatile int sink`? (Maybe it means something like "make sure the `sink` is not optimized by the compiler"?)
2. Why `volatile` for `sink`? I think almost every compiler might know the `std::accumulate` will change the value of `sink`.

I thought I knew what `volatile` and "side-effect" meant, but maybe I'm missing some point!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
 
volatile int sink;
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << std::left;
    for (auto size = 1ull; size < 1000'000'000ull; size *= 100) {
        // record start time
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        // do some work
        std::vector<int> v(size, 42);

        // This is the line I mentioned.
        sink = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0u); // make sure it's a side effect

        // record end time
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
        std::cout << "Time to fill and iterate a vector of " << std::setw(9)
                  << size << " ints : " << diff.count() << " s\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: How *exactly* does the duplicate answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily.

C++ has the 'as if' rule. The compiler must generate code that works 'as if' the source code was executed, but it doesn't have to do everything that the source code does, in exactly the same order.

Now look at the `sink` variable. After the line you mention it's never used again. So it's value has no visible effect on the program. So why should the compiler bother calculating it's value? Because of the as if rule it is perfectly legal for the compiler not to do so.

But there are a few exceptions to the as if rule, and one of them is `volatile` variables. Reads and writes to volatile variables must occur in exactly the way that the source code says. That's why volatile is important in this code. It forces the compiler to execute the `std::accumulate` call even though it has no visible effect on the program.

Further reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

Answer (score 2):

The issue in the code sample given is that the value of `sink` is never used after it has been calculated. Thus, a compiler would be free to "optimize out" the call to `std::accumulate`, as doing so would have no observable effect.

Adding the `volatile` qualifier to `sink` prevents such an undesired optimization. From [another cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) (bold emphasis mine):

> ***volatile object*** - An object whose type is *volatile-qualified*, or a subobject of a
> volatile object, or a mutable subobject of a const-volatile object.
> ***Every access*** (read or write operation, member function call, etc.) made through a glvalue expression of volatile-qualified type
> ***is treated as a visible side-effect for the purposes of optimization*** (that is, within a single thread of execution,
> volatile accesses cannot be optimized out or reordered with another
> visible side effect that is sequenced-before or sequenced-after the
> volatile access. …)

Answer (score 1):

The example code referenced is intended to show timing functions.
The C++ standard allows the compiler to look at some code, and remove it, if it believes the result is not used.

The example uses `volatile` and the side effect to be sure that the timing is not optimized away by the compiler.